# How to run the query to update thousands of rows at once, instead of one update for each result?

Tags: php, mysql

I am running a script that run the following code for all of the users and update the MySQL database. Currently, it updates more than 400.000 times, something that it is huge for the processing power of my server.

```
while($usersResult = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_users)) {   

    $percentile_rank = $percentile_rank * $user_variable / 100);
    mysql_query("UPDATE new_table SET percentile_visits_frequency='$percentile_rank' WHERE hash='$usersResult[hash]'");

}
```

I wonder if there is a way to edit the code, in order to update 1000, 2000 or 10.000 `hash` with one query, instead 1 query for each `hash`.

Thank you

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Since each percentile is unique to the hash you would have to run a query for each, unless I misunderstand your purpose.

Comment: @JayBlanchard true about PDO. Also, the perentile_rank is unique for each hash

Comment: Then it would seem you have no choice. [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16977898/mysql-optimizing-insert-speed-being-slowed-down-because-of-indices) for some helpful tips.

Comment: You could make an `update` statement with a `select`, like displayed in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262786/mysql-update-query-based-on-select-query). The select query can be range of simple `select $percentile_rank as percentile_rank , $user_variable as user_variable` which are *union alled* together. You could do that with parameters too. Just add question marks for the variables and bind the values. Anyway. It's a tad more complicated, but worth it in terms of performance.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I put a thought on it, and I can group similar `percentile_rank`

Comment: You have a query which is creating the `$get_users`. Then you have `percentile_rank` and `$user_variable` variables. I do not know the relation between these two variables and `$get_users`. But if they have any relation, maybe you can create a single query which updates all the records you have in `$get_users` with the calculation of `percentile_rank` inside the query itself

Comment: Without knowing the initial query that populates `$usersResult`, the potential values of `$user_variable`, or even the barest description of what any of this *does* it's nigh-impossible to answer your question.