# MySQL INSERT slowing down with increasing rows

Tags: python, mysql

I have a `python` script which appends rows into a `mysql` table.
But in course of time the insertion is becoming quite slow.
For eg :- When the table was empty there would be like `2000 insertions/sec`.
And when table was filled with like `1 million rows`, the insertion rate dropped to `100 insertions/sec`.
Storage engine is `MyISAM`.
Also,I am not doing indexing

---

Does anybody have any idea what i may be doing wrong or is there any configuration setting which needs to be changed.

Comment: See this (should give you an insight of why) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16977898/mysql-optimizing-insert-speed-being-slowed-down-because-of-indices

Comment: I think it's related to a buffer that gets full or index updating takes longer the bigger it is. [Helpful link 1](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/myisam-key-cache.html) and [helpful link 2](https://www.percona.com/blog/2006/09/29/what-to-tune-in-mysql-server-after-installation/) .

Comment: Thanks, is there a way around for this??